# How to add product specific meta in opencart

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, opencart

I am trying to add meta tags that are product specific. For example og:image, product price, etc.

Google and twitter do not throw any error or warning but Facebook throws a warning if I add the meta inside the `<body>` tag instead of the `<head>` tag.

I tried using the following code but nothing showed.

```
<?php if ($page == 'product/product') { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $thumb; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but Facebook throws a warning if I add the meta inside the `<body>` tag instead of the `<head>` tag.

The `meta`element is only allowed in the `head` element, not in `body`.

That’s defined in the HTML specifications – so go fix this *error*.

Comment: I am aware that it is allowed in head element only.

What I want to know is since the `$thumb` returns null in `head.tpl`, is there any other way where I can add the meta data from the scope of `$thumb` through a function call.

Comment: And why are you adding them to the `body` then …?